# Adding a line to axes.Subplot while preserving datetime x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to improve a spaghetti plot by creating a subplot with all my lines, then highlighting the most important line by bolding it, changing colors, etc. However, when I add the new line, I get strange behavior.

```
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(100)][::-1]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3), index=date_list)
df.iloc[:50, 2] = np.nan

ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 7.7),title='test')
```

In this line, I get the weird behavior

```
ax.plot(frame_trunc.iloc[:,2], color='orange', linewidth=4)
```

I don't understand this behavior. Why are the initial lines scrunching together? I would have assumed that the x-values would be the same between the two.

Comment: Your second plot should also use pandas plotting instead of directly accessing matplotlib. `frame_trunc.plot(frame_trunc.iloc[:,2], ..., ax=ax)`.  Depending what exactly is in  `frame_trunc` this could give the desired result.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, this solved my issue. I did not realize that, even though pandas uses matplotlib, I needed to be consistent. A related question: what is an effective way of editing the legend on the first pandas plot to match the line parameters of the second pandas plot?